# When i scan for my website domain google search gives spam links , how to remove it

Tags: wordpress, xss, malware, google-search-console

The website is a wordpress site and it was been attacked by xss attack. Ive already installed **wordfence** and **malcare** to scan and remove the malicious code and files. but still the google search results are show spam links under the main result. I most of the pages direct to 404 webpages and i was told the google bot will remove it automatically but the issue still remains after 4 days. if any expert regarding this have any solutions and advice i would much appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try resubmitting you sitemap to Google in the Search Console.

Otherwise, similiarly try using the Google Removals tool to temporarily these links, hopefully the will be cleared from the search results by the the time the links are restored.

Tutorial: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9689846?hl=en